# Mongoose models are not retained after dynamically creating them

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, e-commerce

I am using nodejs, express and mongoose with MongoDB to create a templated sort of e-commerce platform. I am trying to dynamically create models through post requests using my API. I use a single instance of mongoose connection to create these models.

```
const config = require('config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const logger = require('../logger/logger.js');

async function runDB() {
  const db = await mongoose.connect(config.get('database.mongodb.uri'));
  logger.info('Connected to MongoDB');
  return db;
}

module.exports = {
  runDB,
  mongoose, 
};
```

I then use this mongo instance throughout my controllers. I can post my data and it shows up on MongoDB Compass, but when if my server stops the data is not retained and yet when I try to create the model again it says that the model already exists. Here's an example controller function:

```
const postCategory = async function (req, res) {

    req.body.name = standardizeInput(req.body.name);
    const categoryExists = await CategoryModel.findOne({
      name: req.body.name,
    });
    if (categoryExists) {
      return res.status(statusCodes.StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN).json({
        status: false,
        message: 'Category already exists',
        data: null,
      });
    }
    const category = new CategoryModel({
      name: req.body.name,
      description: req.body.description,
      isDeleted: req.body.isDeleted,
    });
    if (mongoose.model[req.body.name]) {
      return res.status(statusCodes.StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN).json({
        status: false,
        message: 'Model already exists',
        data: null,
      });
    }
    if (Object.keys(req.body.description) === 0)
      return res.status(statusCodes.StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).json({
        status: false,
        message: 'Description is empty',
        data: null,
      });
    const newModelForCategory = await createCategoryModel(req);
    category.save().then((result) => {
      const data = _.pick(result, pickProps);
      res.status(statusCodes.StatusCodes.CREATED).json({
        status: true,
        message: 'Category added and model created successfully',
        result: { data },
      });
    });

};

const createCategoryModel = async function (req) {
  const { name, description } = req.body;
  let categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
  Object.keys(description).forEach((field) => {
    const fieldConfig = description[field];
    categorySchema.add({
      [field]: {
        type:
          fieldConfig.type == 'boolean'
            ? Boolean
            : fieldConfig.type == 'number'
            ? Number
            : fieldConfig.type == 'string'
            ? String
            : Mixed,
        required: fieldConfig.required ? true : false,
        min: fieldConfig.min ? fieldConfig.min : 0,
        max: fieldConfig.max ? fieldConfig.max : 512,
      },
    });
  });
  categorySchema.add({
    isDeleted: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  });
  const newModelForCategory = mongoose.model(name, categorySchema);
  return newModelForCategory;
};
```

I cant find a way where I can retain the data in the db. Heres the error I see after I try to add another product to the same category:

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "laptops".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\node_modules\mongoose\lib\mongoose.js:528:13)
    at addCategoryFields (C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\controllers\product.js:59:55)
    at newFn (C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\node_modules\express-async-errors\index.js:16:20)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at body (C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\middleware\validate.js:17:3)
    at C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\routes\Products.js:26:23
    at newFn (C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\node_modules\express-async-errors\index.js:16:20)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\semustax\Documents\Personal\compbus-portal\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
```

Comment: Are you allowing schemas to be created from the front-end using the `req.body` data? If so, I would strongly encourage against this from a security and data integrity perspective.

Comment: @jQueeny right now it's just an api and all the data that can be added is going to be validated. i am not worried about the security risks at the moment. I somehow want to be able to save the models to mongodb rather than being just on the mongoose connection instance. Because when I yse.modelNames() it shows all the models but only as long as I create them in that instance